# Symfony app in Docker doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I created an app in Symfony with MongoDB and I added that in a Docker image.

Image for MongoDB works good with message: `2017-04-19T12:47:33.936+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`

But image for app dosen't work I receive the message:

```
stdin: is not a tty
hello
```

when I call the instruction: `docker run docker_web_server:latest`

I use for that docker-compose file:

```
web_server:
    build: web_server/
    ports:
        - 5000:5000
    links:
        - mongo
    tty: true
    environment:
        SYMFONY__MONGO_ADDRESS: mongo
        SYMFONY__MONGO_PORT: 27017

mongo:
   image: mongo:3.0
   container_name: mongo
   command: mongod --smallfiles
   expose:  
       - 27017
```

And Dockerfile for app is:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    php5-cli \
    php5-json \
    php5-intl

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ADD ./code /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

#RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/www/app/cache/*
exec php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 # This will run a web-server on port 8000
```

What is the problem?

I call wrong the server from docker image?

I expected to have the message:

```
 [OK] Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `CMD ['echo', 'hello']` from your `Dockerfile`, has this is being passed as a parameter to your `ENTRYPOINT`

You should also add `tty: true` to your service definition, `web-server`

I'm hoping `entrypoint.sh` runs `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000` at end. Please post that for further advice. If you do use `php -S` inside of it, prefix it with `exec` to get it to take over as the main process.

### Edit since new information added:

I'd modify the `entrypoint.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/www/app/cache/*
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 # This will run a web-server on port 8000
```

I'd get rid of the `symfony_environment.sh` and instead, add the following to your web-server service:

```
environment:
  SYMFONY__MONGO_ADDRESS: mongo
  SYMFONY__MONGO_PORT: 27017
```

As a side-note, I contribute to a project called `boilr` that generates boilerplates, like this. I've even created a template for php/docker-compose projects, it would be worth checking out. I always keep it up-to-date with the best practices.

https://github.com/rawkode/boilr-docker-compose-php

Comment: I added entrypoint.sh and  symfony_environment.sh files. It's ok the content?

Comment: Shouldn't he bring the services up with `docker-compose up` after building instead of `docker run`? The ports mapping for the web_server looks weird too...

Comment: Good catch, @RenanTaranto - the ports are mapped incorrectly

Comment: I modified the files and now I recived the message: `web_server_1  | _init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` after command docker-compose up. I updated the post with actual files.

Comment: I tried to put `exec` on line 3 in `entrypoint.sh` file => `exec php -S 0.0.0.0:8000`. But the result is same. What I do wrong?

Comment: I added in Dockerfile lines: 
`#RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh" ]` and works.

But now when I access the link http://0.0.0.0:8000/my_api dosen't work. What is the problem now?